# I get an error about "browserObject" on the console only in case of chrome in react app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I'm making an app with React.
Only in Chrome, the following error is output both on localhost and after building and deploying.

it is error.
[image]

I did not find the error caused by what, so let me ask you a question.

The environment is
It is a react app created by "create react app".
The packages used are as follows.

```
        "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.1.1",
        "@mui/material": "^5.1.1",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.1.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-device-detect": "^2.1.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-helmet-async": "^1.1.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
        "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "swr": "^1.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
```

I feel that apps I create with react always get this error.
Is it a problem with material ui?

best regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the webcontent.js file in sources to see what is loading that file in my case it was Endpoint Protection Chrome Browser Extension.

Also load the page using incognito mode to see if you get the same error message.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I didn't think so much because it was a JS error, so I thought it was due to the screen, but as you say, it was due to one of the Chrome extensions.
Your answer solved it!
Best regard.